# vmstat - the r column, does it mean count of process or thread

Tags: linux

When running `vmstat`, the first column `r`, does it mean count of runnable process or thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually threads.

A single multi-threaded process might have a combination of runnable threads and blocked ones at the same time. They are counted separately.

`vmstat` is picking theses values from `/proc/stats` `procs_running` and `procs_blocked` values.

[/proc/stat documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) was corrected to talk about threads, not processes, for `procs_running` but is still misleading for `procs_blocked`:

> The "procs_running" line gives the total number of **threads** that are
>   running or ready to run (i.e., the total number of runnable threads).
>
> The   "procs_blocked" line gives  the  number of  **<s>processes</s>** currently
>   blocked, waiting for I/O to complete.

Comment: Ok, then I think they should describe that more clearly in the man page :)

Comment: I guess you mean, both `procs_running` & `procs_blocked` are actually number of threads.

Comment: @EricWang That's definitely what I mean. Answer edited to make clear where the documentation is misleading.