# Completely confused with vmstat

Tags: linux, kernel, vmstat

So, from what I've found, there are multiple versions of vmstat out there for various OSes like Linux, BSD, and Solaris. I'm referring to Linux's `vmstat  procps-ng 3.3.17` .

Now, to be more specific, there's a column `procs` -> `r`.
The manual says:

> r: The number of runnable processes (running or waiting for run time).

People online say ([like here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264954/vmstat-the-r-column-does-it-mean-count-of-process-or-thread)) that it's actually not processes but threads. Is that the case?

Also, many online articles say this field represents the number of processes (or threads?) waiting for run time only, while the manual explicitly says "running." So I can guess here that the older version of vmstat did not include "running" to this metric, but in this case, what confuses me is why the value is always 0 for me then when I test it? I forked a couple of processes while vmstat was running, tho vmstat always shows 0.

I invested considerable time researching this topic online, but I found the information to be quite diverse and conflicting. Would appreciate any help

Comment: vmstat is just reading /proc/stat which is a virtual file from the current kernel.  there is some details on that in this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326434/does-procs-running-include-the-process-which-issues-requests.  In one of the comments, it mentions that vmstat subtracts one, so that vmstat execution itself doesn't skew the results.    I think it should be clear that an idle process is sleeping, so it isn't technically considered running.  make sure you run active processes (like `ls -lR /`) in order to test vmstat output.

Comment: @toppk thanks! Very useful! Checking now